# How to populate UI Table View with String from Parse

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I am trying to queries a class from Parse, then replace the contents of a UITable with the content from my Parse Class Column. The content is a string.

However, I keep encountering an "AnyObject is not convertible to string error"... I can pull in objectIds, but nothing else.

I'm a newbie learning Swift, would somebody mind helping me out?

```
class ExListTBC: UITableViewController {
var exercises = [" "]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "abExercises")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]! , error: NSError!) -> Void in

        self.exercises.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

            var abItem:PFObject = object as PFObject
              self.exercises.append(abItem.objectForKey("exname"))   

        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I realized that I had to tell Swift that my object was a string. By using OBjectkey method, I was able to declare the object as a string. The completed code that works is

```
 self.exercises.append(abItem.objectForKey("exname") as NSString)
```